# Solving $(1 + ax)^{1/a} = (1 + bx)^{1/b}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Here's the problem:

For positive odd integers $a,b$ with $a > b$, find the solution $x \leq -2/b$ to the equation

$$(1 + ax)^{1/a} = (1 + bx)^{1/b}.$$

I was able to prove that there is only one $x$ with $x < -2/b$ (see below) that satisfies the problem.

By using the substitution $u = 1+bx$, I obtained

$$\left(1 + \frac ab (u-1) \right)^{1/a} = u^{1/b},$$

which led me to the nicer looking equation

$$u^{a/b} - \frac abu + \frac ab -1 = 0.$$

I also noticed that using the substitution $v = u^{1/b}$ led me to

$$v^a - \frac ab v^b + \frac ab -1 = 0,$$

which also yielded

$$\sum_{r=0}^{a-1} v^r - \frac ab\sum_{r=0}^{b-1} v^r = 0,$$

which is an $a-1$ degree polynomial in $v$. Interestingly, the first $b-1$ terms of this polynomial have the same coefficient equal to $1 - a/b$ and the rest have a coefficient equal to $1$.

But, through either of these approaches, I still get stuck. Any help would be much appreciated!

---

Sorry for the late response! There were some mistakes on my part, and I hope to correct them here in this edit.

### **Proof of unique solution $x < -2/b$**.

Begin by raising $a$ on both sides to obtain

$$1 + ax = (1 + bx)^{a/b} \implies 0 = (1 + bx)^{a/b} - ax - 1.$$

Define $f(x) = (1 + bx)^{a/b} - ax - 1$. Its derivative is given by

$$f'(x) = a(1 + bx)^{\frac ab - 1} - a = a((1+bx)^{\frac {a-b}b} - 1).$$

Now, since $a,b$ are both positive odd integers with $a  >b$, we have that $a-b$ is a positive even integer, and thus,

$$(1 + bx)^{\frac{a-b}b} \geq 0$$

holds over all real $x$.

The quantity $(1 + bx)^{\frac{a-b}b} \leq 1$ only when $|1 + bx| \leq 1$, or when $-2/b \leq x \leq 0$, and similarly $(1 + bx)^{\frac{a-b}b} \geq 1$ only when $|1 + bx| \geq 1$, or when either $x \geq 0$ or $x \leq -2/b$.

Finally, note that $(1 + bx)^{\frac{a-b}b} = 1$ when $|1 + bx| = 1$, or when $x = 0$ or $x = -2/b$.

From here, since $a > 0$, we have that

$$f'(x) > 0 \quad \text{when } x \in (-\infty, -2/b) \cup (0, \infty),$$

and

$$f'(x) < 0 \quad \text{when } x \in (-2/b, 0),$$

and

$$f'(x) = 0 \quad \text{when } x = 0, -2/b.$$

Here I've used interval notation to denote the possible values of $x$.

Notice $f(0) = 0$. Since $f$ strictly increases for $x > 0$, we have that $f(x) > f(0) = 0$ for all $x > 0$.

Now, $f$ strictly decreases for $-2/b < x < 0$, so $f(x) > f(0) = 0$, for $-2/b < x < 0$, which implies that there are no roots in the interval $(-2/b, 0)$.

Finally, we note the value $f(-2/b) = 2a/b - 2$, for which, since $a/b > 1$, we have $2a/b - 2 > 0$. The function $f$ strictly increases for $x < -2/b$, so $f(x) < f(-2/b)$, and in particular, $f$ is injective on this interval. That is, on this interval,

$$f(s) = f(t) \implies s = t, \quad \text{for } s,t < -2/b.$$

Since $f(-2/b) > 0$, there is exactly one $x$ with $x < -2/b$ such that $f(x) = 0$, signaling the end of the proof.

For a more visual representation of this proof, see [this Desmos graph.](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/mvcxaj8i1j)

---

I should also mention some background on how I stumbled across this problem. I was investigating a generalization of Bernoulli's inequality, for which the classic version states that

$$(1 + x)^n \geq 1 + nx$$

for $n = 1,2,\dots$ and $x \geq -1$.

In particular, I was investigating the inequality

$$\left(1 + x\right)^{\frac ab} \geq 1 + \frac ab x$$

over real $x$ and positive integers $a,b$ and determining when the above holds. It is known that the above holds for $x \geq -1$, which can be shown with calculus over real $a/b$. ([Here's the Wikipedia page if you're interested.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality))

However, I was more interested with the case in which $x < -1$. There must be additional restrictions, however, in particular $b$ must be odd, or $(1 + x)^{a/b}$ will not be a real number.

I was able to show that the inequality held for all real $x$ when $a$ was even, however, for odd $a$, I had determined that there was a negative nonzero solution to the equation

$$(1 + x)^{a/b} = 1 + \frac ab x.$$

At this solution, say $x_0$, I had that the inequality did not hold for $x < x_0$.

To obtain the original inequality I posted here, you raise both sides by $1/a$ and take the transformation $x \mapsto bx$, which gave the much more aesthetically pleasing equation

$$(1 + ax)^{1/a} = (1 + bx)^{1/b}.$$

From here, I think it would be appropriate to ask a few other questions other than "what's the solution?". In particular, for positive integers $n,m$, if $R(n,m)$ is the solution to the equation,

$$(1 + (2n-1)x)^{2n-1} = (1 + (2m-1)x)^{2m-1},$$

then...

1. Can we approximate $R(n,m)$ to a precise degree? (This one is mostly solved by Newton's method which was mentioned by someone who for some reason I can't find now.)
2. Can we create any identities involving $R(a,b)$?

I am particularly interested with question 2. If I find anything, I'll be sure to add it in another edit to this post. Thanks guys!

Comment: I would have studied first the variation your function of $u$ and prooving it cancels at only one point.

Comment: I know the existence of a solution $x \leq -2$, but I'm trying to find an analytical expression in $x$. I'm not sure how studying how $u$ varies will lead to an exact solution.

Comment: Would you please show this existence?

Comment: Yes! I will edit this, along with more info in.

Comment: Have you considered this fact $\lim_{n\to \infty}(1+\frac{x}{n})^n$ ? You just have to put $a=\frac{1}{n}$ and play with these things . Maybe it gives something...

Comment: All I can say is that $a>b\le e$ since $a^{\frac{1}{a}} \lt b^{\frac{1}{b}}$ when $a>b>e$

Answer (score 1):

I could only solve it with assumptions, like $a$ is an odd number multiply of $b$ which is let to be $\alpha$, and that when arriving at a point when the two sides of the equation are both a product of two terms from which one is $\alpha - 1$ which must be even, then I assumed $\alpha - 1$ is 2, so $\alpha$ is assumed to be 3, and that gave me $b=1$, $a=3$, $x=-3$, and that is a solution. This doesn't prove though that this is the only solution and I guess is almost nothing to do with (pre)calculus. But if needed I can share the steps.

---

**Update**
The statement in the question "*I was able to prove that there is only one $x$*" misses $x\in?$. Because if you are looking for integers only, it might be true, but for reals you can always write up a polynomial for fixed $(a,b)$ as sirous did. My approach is that as $x\le-2$ and $b\ge1$, therefore $bx\le-2$. Now using your definition of $u$, $u\le-1$. Let $-u=t$, $t\ge1$. Using $t$ instead of $u$ we have

$(-t)^{a/b} + \frac abt + \frac ab - 1 = 0$

and as $a$ is odd, $(-t)^{a/b} = -t^{a/b} $

using this and doing rearrangements we get

$\frac abt + \frac ab= t^{a/b} + 1$
$\frac ab = \frac {t^{a/b} + 1}{t + 1}$

as $a\gt b$, the LHS $\gt1$, and as $t\gt1$, $t^{a/b}\gt t \Longrightarrow t^{a/b} + 1 \gt t + 1$, so the RHS $\gt1$ also $\forall t$, except for $t=1$, but for $t\gt 1$ the numerator grows more than the denominator, so though I am unable to prove, but common sense tells me $\exists t\in\mathbb{R}$ $\forall \frac ab$, so there are infinitely many solutions if $x\in\mathbb{R}$. Perhaps one needs to show that the RHS is strictly monotonically increasing, continuous, its minimum value is $1$, does not have a global maximum, and therefore can produce any ratio $\gt1$.

Answer (score 0):

Comment:

We may write:

$(1+ax)^b=(1+bx)^a$

$x^b(\frac{1}{x}+a)^b=x^a(\frac{1}{x}+b)^a$

$x^b=(\frac{1}{x}+b)^a$

$x^a=(\frac{1}{x}+a)^b$

This is the only possible case.

Now if $x<0$ then $(\frac{1}{x}+b)^a>0$, because $\frac{1}{x}$ is a negative fraction and $b$ is a positive integer. which results in $x>0$ which is a contradiction.Similar result comes out from other equation. I wonder how this equation can have negative solutions. Could you show that?
Now let ignore these manupolations and check this with known values for a and b.

Let $a=3$ and $b=1$ we have:

$(1+3x)^1=(1+x)^3$

$x^3+3x^2=0$

Which gives $x=-3$

For $a=5$ and $b=1$ we get $x=-2.85$.

Which shows there can be solutions $x<-2$. But I do not think we can find a parametric solution for $x$ for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: $a,b$ are odd positive integers. If $1/x+b < 0$, then $(1/x+b)^a < 0$. As for showing for a negative solution, let $p=a/b$ and consider the function $f(x) = (1+x)^p -px-1$ and its derivative $f'(x) = p(1+x)^{p-1} -p$. $p-1$ has an even numerator, so $f' > 0$ for $x < -2$.   Thus $f(x) < f(-2)$ for $x<-2$ and $f(-2) > 0$ when $a/b > 1$, or $a>b$. $f''<0$ too so there is only one solution $x < -2$ since $f'$ never equals zero at $x<-2$.

Comment: When you say "This is the only possible case." you forget, that one other scenario is when you multiply one side of both equations by -1. You can do this because the exponents are odd and therefore do not change sign.

Comment: I still can not understand how $1/x+b$ can be less than zero!There i of course one possibility; $|x|<1$, in this case $x $can not be an integer.

Comment: Nohow, but that's why I'm saying $$x^b=-(\frac{1}{x}+b)^a$$ $$x^a=-(\frac{1}{x}+a)^b$$ so $$-x^b(\frac{1}{x}+a)^b=-x^a(\frac{1}{x}+b)^a$$ and the negative sign cancels.

Comment: Something is wrong here: your claimed solution of $a=5,b=1,x=-2.85$ does not work when plugged back in to the equations at the start of your post.

Comment: @KReiser My edit did not make it totally: -2.85 is still a typo. It is -2.65.

Comment: @DávidLaczkó I think it is better to let the answerer know instead of just correcting it. Anyways, your proposed edit did not completely address the lack of mathjax in the post and I decided to edit to fix that starting from the original version of the post.

Comment: @KReiser But can't the poster of the question/answer accept my edit of her/his own post as at stackoverflow.com?

Comment: @DávidLaczkó my objection stems from the fact that edits are supposed to preserve the intent of the author, and mistakes which are important enough (like the key example that's being added) would seem to have enough intent behind them to warrant not changing without asking first. Anyways, I don't think this specific instance is a big enough thing to warrant much of a care from me - I'm only here because I was looking at the review queue. Feel free to propose another edit changing it, I won't get in your way with this post.

Answer (score 0):

I strongly doubt that there is a general solution except in special cases, as
$$(1+ax)^b=(1+bx)^a$$
results in a polynomial of "high" degree.  A special case is $a=3b$; it's easily shown the negative solution is $x=-3/b$.

Furthermore it's quite obvious the negative solution is the zero of a polynomial of degree $a/\operatorname{gcd}(a,b)-2$.